# How to fit the width of BasicTextField with OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox and label

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to fit the width of `BasicTextField` that has a `decorationBox` with `OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox` that has a label.

I tried with `width(IntrinsicSize.Min)` and works fine when I have some text in the filed.

[image]

When the text is empty, I want to show a label, but then the size of the field doesn't fit the label.

[image]

The code of my BasicTextField:

```
BasicTextField(
        modifier        = modifier
            .background(
                color = backgroundColor,
                shape = CircleShape
            )
            .height(44.dp),
        value           = value,
        onValueChange   = onValueChange,
        readOnly        = true,
        singleLine      = maxLines == 1,
        maxLines        = maxLines,
        enabled         = enabled,
        textStyle = TextStyle(
            fontFamily      = carosoft,
            fontWeight      = FontWeight.Light,
            fontSize        = 14.sp,
            lineHeight      = 12.sp,
            letterSpacing   = 0.4.sp,
            color           = colors.onBackground,
            textAlign       = textAlign,
        ),
        decorationBox   = { innerTextField ->
            TextFieldDefaults.OutlinedTextFieldDecorationBox(
                value                = value,
                innerTextField       = innerTextField,
                visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                singleLine           = true,
                enabled              = true,
                interactionSource    = interactionSource,
                contentPadding       = PaddingValues(horizontal = 16.dp, vertical = 0.dp),
                leadingIcon          = leadingIcon,
                border               = { Box(modifier = Modifier.border(BorderStroke(borderWidth, borderColor), CircleShape)){ } } ,
                trailingIcon         = trailingIcon,
                label                = if (label.isNotEmpty()) {{ Texts.Body1(text = label, color = colors.onSurface) }} else null,
                placeholder          = placeholder
            )
        },
        visualTransformation = visualTransformation
    )
```

Could you please help me resolve this issue ?